# mySQL order and Group By

Tags: mysql, sql

Any idea how I can do this?

I want to GROUP BY Fault and Stream and Part but within these groupings I want to sort by Frequency?

Please help.

Mick

```
select
p.part_no as Part,
p.product_description as Description,
p.brand_id as Brand,
p.part_product_family as Stream,
p.range as Range_Name,
fa.description as Area,
f.description as Fault,
count(f.description) as Frequency

from recorded_faults rf, faults f, fault_areas fa, losses l, products p


WHERE rf.fault_id = f.id
and f.fault_area_id = fa.id
and rf.loss_id = l.id
and p.id = l.product_id

group by
Fault,
Stream,
Part

order by Frequency desc
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: It just does the ORDER BY for all the records, not within the grouping.

Comment: Either the first condition of the `WHERE` clause **and** the `WHERE` keyword are missing or the first `AND` should be `WHERE`, to have a syntactically correct query.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: `GROUP BY` produces one row in the output for each combination of the expressions it contains (`Fault, Stream, Part` for this query). There is no such thing like *"order by within grouping"* except for the value produced by function `GROUP_CONCAT()` but you don't use it. What you probably mean is the order of the rows that have the same value for `Fault` or `Fault` and `Stream`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select
p.part_no as Part,
p.product_description as Description,
p.brand_id as Brand,
p.part_product_family as Stream,
p.range as Range_Name,
fa.description as Area,
f.description as Fault,
count(f.description) as Frequency
from recorded_faults rf inner join faults f on rf.fault_id = f.id
                        inner join fault_areas fa on f.fault_area_id = fa.id
                        inner join losses l on rf.loss_id = l.id
                        inner join products p on p.id = l.product_id

group by
p.part_no,
p.product_description,
p.brand_id,
p.part_product_family,
p.range,
fa.description,
f.description,
order by count(f.description) desc
```

*Try to avoid comma seperated JOINS, they are not recommended anymore*

Also you need to put the columns of your `select` in the `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the rows returned for subgroups together then you have to sort the rows by (a prefix of) the same criteria you use for grouping then add any extra expressions you need.

For example, if you want to get the rows having the same value for `Fault` together and sort them by `Frequency` without caring about `Stream` then you write:

```
GROUP BY Fault, Stream, Part
ORDER BY Fault, Frequency DESC
```

If you want to also keep together the rows having the same values of `Fault` and `Stream` then you also add `Stream` to the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
GROUP BY Fault, Stream, Part
ORDER BY Fault, Stream, Frequency DESC
```

It doesn't make any sense to `ORDER BY Fault, Stream, Part, ...` because `GROUP BY` produces a single row for each combination of `Fault`, `Stream` and `Part`.

---

As a side note, SQL allows you to order the rows by other criteria too. For example, `GROUP BY Fault, Stream, Part ORDER BY Part, Fault, Frequency DESC` is perfectly valid and produces correct results, but it is, most probably, meaningless for the business implemented by your application.

Comment: Just shown it to my customer, if I can ROLLUP on Fault and Stream, they will be happy. Currently have GROUP BY Fault, Area, Part
ORDER BY Fault, Stream,Frequency DESC